# How to force akka akka.event.LoggingReceive log messages in play framework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, slf4j

I have the following actor, how can I force it all messages, when it comes to actor

```
class NewsActor @Inject()(wsClient: WSClient, appConfig: AppConfig)
                         (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Actor {

  import ArticleJsonParser._

  override def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case RequestNews =>
      val futureArticles = wsClient.url(News.TECH_URL)
        .withQueryString("source" -> News.SOURCE, "apiKey" -> appConfig.newsApiKey)
        .get() map { response =>
          (Json.parse(response.body) \ "articles").as[Seq[Article]]
      }
      pipe(futureArticles).to(sender())
    case _ => Logger.error("NewsActor message not supported failed")
  }
}
```

As read at akka documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/logging.html and play documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger
I mixed it up and add the following application.conf:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  actor {
    debug {
      # enable function of LoggingReceive, which is to log any received message at
      # DEBUG level
      receive = on
    }
  }
}
```

and following logback.xml

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2009-2016 Lightbend Inc. <https://www.lightbend.com>
  -->
<!-- The default logback configuration that Play uses in dev mode if no other configuration is provided -->
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

    <!-- Set logging for all Akka library classes to INFO -->
    <logger name="akka" level="DEBUG" />
    <!-- Set a specific actor to DEBUG -->
    <!--<logger name="actors.*" level="DEBUG" />-->

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Currently in application console I only see

```
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[debug] a.e.EventStream - logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
[debug] a.e.EventStream - Default Loggers started
[debug] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
```

UPDATE:
When I replace `loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]` with `loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]` it started print messages but it prints it not via play logger.
Log:

```
[debug] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
[DEBUG] [11/04/2016 13:03:19.743] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream(akka://application)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [11/04/2016 13:03:19.743] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream(akka://application)] Default Loggers started
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
[DEBUG] [11/04/2016 13:03:19.863] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://application/user/news-actor] received handled message RequestNews from Actor[akka://application/temp/$a]
```

While it should also print that message is received by actor, what is wrong with my configuration?